# Python: Flatten a list of lists of single floats stored in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I load some data to a pandas dataframe using pyodbc.  The database contains list of lists of a single float number. Given dataframe name is `df` , `type(df.iloc[0][0]` , `type(df.iloc[0][0][0]` give `list` as  an output when `type(df.iloc[0][0][0][0]` give `float` .
I need to flatten those lists down in order to get just the numbers and in the end to just have a list of numbers instead a list of lists.

Just for visualization here is what is saved in `df.iloc[0][0]` :

```
[[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [32.09984], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.40704], [0.40704], [32.09984], [32.061440000000005], [32.048640000000006], [32.01024], [0.49152000000000007], [0.0], [0.00256], [0.00512], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]]
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is the length of this list the same all over the dataframe?? And the sublists have _always_ just one single element?

Comment: Yes, sorry for tha lack of info.
 They are all the same, except a column which i can remove and add later in the main process .  All the sublists have a single float type element and they are equally long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind working with a numpy array you can just do:

```
df.iloc[0][0] = numpy.array(df.iloc[0][0]).flatten()
```

or here the code to do it for a whole column

```
df["Column"] = df["Column"].apply(lambda x : np.array(x).flatten())
```

and if your data needs to be a list later on:

```
df["Column"] = df["Column"].apply(lambda x : list(np.array(x).flatten()))
```

For all columns:

```
for col in df.columns:
   if col not in ["ColumnThatShouldNotBeTransformed1", "ColumnThatShouldNotBeTransformed2"]:
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x : np.array(x).flatten())
```

Comment: So maybe something like 
`for i in cols:   your answer` will do the job for the whole df

Comment: Yes if you want to transform all columns. otherwise you need to add an if statement. Note that it only works if every sublist has exact one element

Comment: Is there any other pythonic way to do that or should i just iterate ? Thanks

Comment: I've none in mind. I would just iterate. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

If all sublists contain single element:

```
>>> x = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [32.09984], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.40704], [0.40704], [32.09984], [32.061440000000005], [32.048640000000006], [32.01024], [0.49152000000000007], [0.0], [0.00256], [0.00512], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]]

>>> list(map(lambda a:a[0],x))
```

Otherwise:

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> list(chain(*x))
```

Replace `x` with `df.iloc[0][0]`

Answer (score 0):

From pandas 0.25 on you could try [`df.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

*mcve:*

```
# ltest = [[0], [314], [42]]
# df = pd.DataFrame([[ltest, ltest, ltest], [ltest, ltest, ltest]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

#                     A                   B                   C
# 0  [[0], [314], [42]]  [[0], [314], [42]]  [[0], [314], [42]]
# 1  [[0], [314], [42]]  [[0], [314], [42]]  [[0], [314], [42]]
```

approach:
create new dataframe:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for c in df.columns:
    df_new[c] = df[c].explode().str.get(0)

#      A    B    C
# 0    0    0    0
# 0  314  314  314
# 0   42   42   42
# 1    0    0    0
# 1  314  314  314
# 1   42   42   42
```

index not unique anymore -> create multiindex:

```
ct = df_new.groupby(df_new.index).cumcount()

# 0    0
# 0    1
# 0    2
# 1    0
# 1    1
# 1    2
# dtype: int64

df_new.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df_new.index, ct])
```

result:

```
#        A    B    C
# 0 0    0    0    0
#   1  314  314  314
#   2   42   42   42
# 1 0    0    0    0
#   1  314  314  314
#   2   42   42   42
```

or with former sub list elements as rows as a matter of taste:

```
df_new.unstack()

#    A           B           C         
#    0    1   2  0    1   2  0    1   2
# 0  0  314  42  0  314  42  0  314  42
# 1  0  314  42  0  314  42  0  314  42
```

---

Now you can index these data quite convenient as usual with Pandas, just note that the multiindex needs a tuple:

```
df_new.loc[0, 1]

# A    314
# B    314
# C    314
# Name: (0, 1), dtype: int64


df_new.loc[(0, 2), 'B']

# 42


df_new.loc[(0, slice(None)), 'B']

# 0  0      0
#    1    314
#    2     42
# Name: 1, dtype: int64
```